# pgfplots: box axis remove one axis keeping 3

Tags: pgfplots

I'm recreating a very special plot, where two plots that share an x axis are *glued* on top of each other. Both have box axis. To make this look good I would like to remove one of the two horizontal axis in a set of box axis. Any advise on how to do this? `hide x axis` removes both top and bottom, I'd like to keep only one.

Here is an MWE: to play with.

**EDIT**: I've removed the x tick marks. Note that `axis x line=top` gives tick marks at both sides of the top axis and introduces an arrow. Both not wanted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,height=10cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=10,
    domain=0:4,
    xticklabels={,,},
%    hide x axis,
    ]
  \addplot+[blue,mark=none,samples=100] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `axis x line=bottom` or `axis x line=top`.

Comment: @esdd then the top line has tick marks above and below the line, and an arrow. I probably should have mentioned that I also removed the numbers in the x axis leaving just the marks, will update the mwe

Comment: Then use the starred version: `axis x line*=bottom` or `axis x line*=top`.

Comment: @esdd Ahh, that worked, make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axis x line` or `axis x line*` to choose which axis x lines should be drawn. Possible values are `box` (default), `top`, `middle`, `center`, `bottom` or `none`. While the starred version only changes the location of the axis the non starred version also affects some other keys. So you can use

```
axis x line*=top
```

to remove the bottom line.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=10cm,height=10cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=10,
    domain=0:4,
    xticklabels={,,},
    axis x line*=top% <- added
    ]
  \addplot+[blue,mark=none,samples=100] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```